# Как получить значение из input в php code

Tags: php

Изучаю php. Не понимаю почему не приходят значения. Вроде ничего сложного. Но судя по адресной строке приходит в итоге только num1 и он же переписывается (http://php/cycle/code.php?**num1=1&num1=5**). Не понимаю в чём ошибка, может openserver чудит, или чего то самм не догоняю пока. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Пример html

```
 <form action="code.php" method="GET">
    Число 1: <p><input type="text" name="num1"></p>
    Число 2: <p><input type="text" name="num2"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="start">
</form>
```

пример php

```
<?php 
var_dump($_GET);

$num1 = $_GET['num1'];
$num2 = $_GET['num2'];


for ($i=$num1; $i<=$num2; $i++){
    echo $i." ";
}
?>
```

Comment: Так вы передаете только `num1`  дважды

Comment: Точно у второго инпута `name="num2"`?

Comment: точно у второго "num2". Оттого и непонятно почему num1 переписывается.

Answer (score -1):

В вашем случае лучше использовать встроенный метод `filter_input`: `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search', ТИП_ФИЛЬТРА);`. Вместо ТИП_ФИЛЬТРА надо указать [пресеты из списка](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.validate.php).

URL: `http://php/cycle/code.php?num1=1&num2=5`

Code:

```php
$num1 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'num1', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$num2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'num2', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);


for ($i=$num1; $i<=$num2; $i++){
    echo $i." ";
}
```

Comment: Как это поможет автору если он сам замечает что у урле у него `?num1=1&num1=5`?

Comment: @u_mulder это не повод не помогать автору.